# Wordpress jQuery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax-error

I am ready to pull my hair out trying to debug this code. I have a page that needs to show numerous sub-posts in the same page without going to another page, however I cannot get the code to work but I cannot find anything wrong. I have even deleted it completely and re-wrote it from scratch to try to find the error but nothing and as always javascript is horrible in pointing the error out to me. I have tried firebug, jslint and made the same structure in jsfiddle but I cannot find the problem. I will say that the same code worked fine in jsfiddle but nowhere else. I see that the page is loading jquery correctly so the api is not the issue. Please help, I do not know what else to do!

Here is the code structure:

HTML-Post Nav

```
<ul id="sub_select">
  <li class="select">
   <a href="#post1">Post 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="select">
   <a href="#post2">Post 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

HTML-Posts

```
<div id="post1" class="about_txt">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Post 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <p>The post itself</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="post2" class="about_txt" style="display: none;">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Post 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <p>The post itself</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery script :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".about_txt").hide('slow');
        var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
        $(toShow).show('slow');
    });​
});
```

UPDATE: I've added the $ that I apparently forgot to copy, but thanks for pointing this out. I still have the issue though.

Comment: Do you have `$` for your document selector?

Comment: You missed the `$`.  `$(document)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be an "invisible" character at the end of this code:

```
$(".select a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".about_txt").hide('slow');
    var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
    $(toShow).show('slow');
});​  //<= There's an invisible character here, 
     //    you can try pressing backspace once at the end of the semicolon
```

For quick fix, delete the invisible character OR copy&paste the following code and replace yours:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".about_txt").hide('slow');
        var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
        $(toShow).show('slow');
    });
});
```

Edit: A bit of investigation shows that the invisible character is [ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%E2%80%8B&han=Y&preview=none)

Answer (score 1):

This line  `(document).ready(function()` should be `$(document).ready(function()` 
It should have a **$** symbol before the document..

To double check comment out the click event and place a alert in it.. Check if the alert fires then.

Comment: Yes, apparently when I copied the code over, I missed that one. It's there however, thanks for pointing it out anyway.